# I got Exception from MySql and it won't Update table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

When I pass the button on click event, with all Jcomponats value, It won't update my table instead of that It reflect exception while my code is working properly in other table?

```
private void update() {
    String id = txtPcno.getText();
    String updateQuery = "insert into n_patient (name, gender, NRIC, nationality, height, weight, smoke, last_seen) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

        //pst.setString(1, txtPcno.getText());
        pst.setString(1, txtName.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtGender.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtNRIC.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtNationality.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txtHeight.getText());
        pst.setString(6, txtWeight.getText());
        pst.setString(7, txtSmoke.getText());
        pst.setString(8, txtLastSeen.getText());

        int rowAffected = pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format(" %d Modified Records Are Saved ", rowAffected));
        clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Here is the Image of indication Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7nDI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because,

- While inserting a record into that table, you do not insert data for that('Pcno') column and this column having a property like the 'not nullable' and 'primary key'.

  - In this scenario two option to solve that issue,

    1. Make that column as auto-increment column,
       Or
    2. While inserting the record into that table also pass the value of the 'Pcno' column

Comment: I had used option 2 but I got exception.... Then I comment it, you can saw this comment on Code.

Comment: 1. update your query with,
   `insert into n_patient (pcno,name, gender, NRIC, nationality, height, weight, smoke, last_seen) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`
2. After that add set statement for pcno as, 
  `pst.setString(1, id);
   pst.setString(2, txtName.getText());
   pst.setString(3, txtGender.getText());
   pst.setString(4, txtNRIC.getText());
   pst.setString(5, txtNationality.getText());
   pst.setString(6, txtHeight.getText());
   pst.setString(7, txtWeight.getText());
   pst.setString(8, txtSmoke.getText());
   pst.setString(9, txtLastSeen.getText());`